# Using mulitple colors in a single gmaps polyline

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Im trying to create an applicatie that displays routes on a map as a polyline. On the Route/polyline i would like to have some visual display of how busy the route was at that point. My idea is to use a color with blue indicating it was not busy and red indicating a busy part op the route.
This way the map should end up with a single route displayed with blue and red and all colors in between.
On the google maps api i found the method to set the color `PolylineOptions.color(int color)` of the polyline. But i see no option to provide different colors on different segments of the line.

Is there a way to use multiple colors on a single polyline in google maps android api?

Reference to the google maps documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolylineOptions.html

Comment: no you need to separate the lines if you want to change the color of a section

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of colors

```
var Colors = [
    "#FF0000", 
    "#00FF00", 
];
```

Now, instead of drawing one polyline, draw a separate polyline for each coordinate.

```
for (var i = 0; i < DrivePath.length-1; i++) {
  var PathStyle = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [DrivePath[i], DrivePath[i+1]],
    strokeColor: Colors[i],
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    map: map
  });
}
```

Comment: Your example denotes using multiple polylines and is writen in java script. Can this example be translated into android java code?